# Passing values from one function to another with React navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I would like to pass the value "Hello" from App.js to screen1.js. Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@mobshed/passing-data-between-functions

Thank you for your help!

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import MyScreen from './screen1'

export default function Root() {
    return <MyScreen show="Hello" />;
}
```

screen1.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createStackNavigator
} from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function screenPage ({show}) {
  alert(show)
  return (<View style={{ justifyContent: "center", flex: 1}}><Text>Hello world</Text></View>)
}

export default function Root({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        gestureEnabled: false,
        gestureDirection: "horizontal"
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        name="screenPage"
        component={screenPage}
      />   
    </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you post your code on codesandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-sky-dhvpx?from-embed (but it keeps on giving me a dependency error). Snack version works tho: https://snack.expo.io/@mobshed/passing-data-between-functions

Comment: okay , i will try to help you solve this problem.

Comment: get the props in screen1 as export default ({navigation, show}) => {}

Comment: @AshwithSaldanha Yes, that would work but I can't export that screen as default since I'm planning on adding more functions/screen pages.

Comment: u can export and import like this export const Screen1 = ({navigation, show}) = {};  import {Screen!} from './screen1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in screen1.js:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createStackNavigator
} from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function screenPage ({route}) {
  const {show} = route.params;
  alert(show);
  return (<View style={{ justifyContent: "center", flex: 1}}><Text>Hello world</Text></View>)
}

export default function Root({ navigation, show }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        gestureEnabled: false,
        gestureDirection: "horizontal"
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        name="screenPage"
        component={screenPage}
        initialParams={{show: show}}
      />   
    </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Another way, you can pass params something like this:

```
<Button
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          // Pass params back to screenPage
          navigation.navigate('screenPage', { show: "hello" });
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it! Thanks Khanh for putting me on the right path earlier before you deleted your answer

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createStackNavigator
} from "@react-navigation/stack";
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function screenPage ({route}) {
  alert(route.params.user)
  return (<View style={{ justifyContent: "center", flex: 1}}><Text>Hello world</Text></View>)
}

export default function Root({ navigation, show}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        gestureEnabled: false,
        gestureDirection: "horizontal"
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        name="screenPage"
        component={screenPage}
        initialParams={{ user: show }}
      />   
    </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```